# Need understand $.fn.yiiGridView.update ajax

Tags: ajax, yii

I have a simple function in js.

```
function goalert(){ alert('go'); }
```

When use $.fn.yiiGridView.update, i rewrite complete,

```
$.fn.yiiGridView.update('me-grid',{ complete: function(){ goalert(); } });
```

But, launch firts goalert() and after update cviewgried.

One solution is:

```
$.fn.yiiGridView.update('edificis-grid',{ complete: function(jqXHR, status) {
                    if (status=='success'){
                        goalert();
                    }
                }});
```

In this case, firts update and after launch goalert().

What is the explanation?

Comment: Do you try to debug your code and yiiGridView.update ?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call goalert() before calling yiiGridView.update(). I have done similar thing in my code and it works fine.
instead of alert make alert a dialog. Open it before update and close it at callback.

```
    $('#goAlert').dialog('open');
    $.fn.yiiGridView.update('edificis-grid',{ complete: function(jqXHR, status) {
                    if (status=='success'){
                        $('#goAlert').dialog('close');
                    }
                }});
```

For me, its working fine.